# Change button text when overflow?

Tags: css, html, button, overflow

I have a button that scales with the width of the page. When it gets too small, the text wraps and thus becomes unreadable. I want the button to go from "Post Thread" to "Post" and then to just a + sign. What is the easiest way to do this, preferably with just CSS and HTML, though other languages are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate containers for each text, one for large resolutions, and one for smaller resolutions.

Then use media queries to show/hide them, like this:

```css
/* Hide when larger than 768px */     
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .visible-sm { display: none; }
}

/* Hide when smaller than 768px */    
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .visible-lg { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">
    <span class="visible-lg">Post Thread</span>
    <span class="visible-sm">+ Post</span>
</a>
```